# button in listview opens new activity

Tags: listview, button, android-activity

I have a listView and each list has a button. I want to start a new activity on clicking the button. The PairingActivity already extends ListView. What should I do?
Wont onClickListener work?Should i use OnItemClickListener?If yes, then how? 
I am new to android programming. Please help me. Thanx in advance.

```
public class PairingActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener 
{
    private Button afterConnectBtn;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_multidevice);

        Log.v("", "Activity started after connecting");
        afterConnectBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.connect_button);
        afterConnectBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
         }//end of onCreate()

      @Override

    public void onItemClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.connect_button:
         Intent pairIntent = new Intent(PairingActivity.this,
                    ThirdActivity.class);
            startActivity(pairIntent);
            break;
            }
    }
```